# Nyquist plot - what is the meaning of circles with dB values on complex plane

Tags: control-theory, matlab

Let's start with arbitrary transfer function as an example, such as:

```
obj = tf([1 2],[1 0 2 5]);
nyquist(obj);
grid on;
axis([-2 2 -2 2]); axis equal
```

As far as I do understand what is gain (expressed in dB), I am unable to figure out, nor find any information about circles that appear after we use `grid`. For some reason there is vertical line at `Re=-0.5` associated with `0 dB` value. On the left and right of this line we see non coincident circles in the shape of peacock's eye with decreasing or increasing values. Circles converge to points `[-1,0]` and `[0,0]`.

We can see that system's curve starts at point `[-0.4,0]` which corresponds to `-7.9588 dB` gain, crosses `-10 dB` circle twice, where on both occurrences system's gain doesn't match `-10 dB` value.

Moreover, just from the fact that that we have infinite line denoted with `0 dB` value, one can infer that it has absolutely nothing to do with actual gain, which on Nyquist plot should be circular around point `[0,0]`. In this case my question is simple: what does those dB values  and circles mean?

[image: Nyquist plot with grid on]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`doc nyquist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/nyquist.html):

> The nyquist function has support for M-circles, which are the contours of 
>   the constant closed-loop magnitude. M-circles are defined as the locus of 
>   complex numbers where
>
> $$T(j\omega) = \left|\dfrac{G(j\omega)}{(1+G(j\omega))}\right|$$
>
> is a constant value. In this equation, $\omega$ is the frequency in 
>   radians/TimeUnit, where TimeUnit is the system time units, and $G$ is the
>   collection of complex numbers that satisfy the constant magnitude 
>   requirement.

Comment: M-circles is the phrase that I have been looking for. I checked Matlab documentation before, but I must have miss this section. I also found some more information about this in The Control Handbook, section 9.2.2, page 140. It is available on [Google][1].

  [1]: https://books.google.pl/books?id=2WQP5JGaJOgC&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=m-circles+nyquist+plot&source=bl&ots=P5oNOjzfBP&sig=8q4D1D9CiMlODPUel5H1oxzAyR8&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv-KjD6s_UAhXkApoKHUYZARQQ6AEIWTAK#v=onepage&q=m-circles%20nyquist%20plot&f=false